# How to save file descriptor returned from gdbus call in bash?

Tags: bash, dbus, gdbus

I'm trying to use

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo gdbus call -y -d org.freedesktop.login1 \
                   -o /org/freedesktop/login1 \
                   -m org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.Inhibit \
                   sleep me because block
sleep 10
```

to acquire an inhibitor lock in a bash script. The introspection for this method looks like this:

```
Inhibit(in  s what,
        in  s who,
        in  s why,
        in  s mode,
        out h pipe_fd);
```

After my call to `gdbus` is done, no inhibitor lock is shown as acquired when listing with `systemd-inhibit --list`. I assume this is because the lock is acquired and then immediately released when exiting from `gdbus`.

How can I duplicate the returned file descriptor, `pipe_fd`, from the method call so it doesn't release the lock immediately after exiting from the call?

Comment: [`dup(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html) will not help you. It affects only to a single process. But your shell script is a combination of many processes. See `apropos dup`. You will not find anything like `dup` in chapter 1 user commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I duplicate the returned file descriptor, `pipe_fd`, from the method call so it doesn't release the lock immediately after exiting from the call?

You can’t do that with the command line `gdbus` tool, as it exits immediately after making the D-Bus call, and hence the FD is returned to the kernel.

You will need to write a script in some other language (perhaps Python) which makes the D-Bus call and then does something appropriate with the returned FD *before* it exits. In that case, you may find it easier to use systemd’s own Python bindings rather than making a D-Bus call directly.

Alternatively, you could wrap your bash script in a call to `systemd-inhibit`, which is a command line utility to inhibit shutdown while another script is running.

Comment: I was trying to avoiding having to wrap the script with `system-inhibit` but it would be too much of a hassle to use another language to take advantage of dbus.

Comment: As far as I can think, those are your options.